# Custom NSTextView autocompletion menu

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

How would one implement a  custom auto-complete pop-up menu like Xcode has?

At the moment I can only put custom auto-completions using

```
- (NSArray *)textView:theTextView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(int *)index
```

I want a bit more flexibility than this.

Cheers!

MT

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm looking to do something similar and have not made it very far yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xcode (and other apps) use a custom auto-completion view. You can bring up your view at the correct location using the text view's layout manager's method `locationForGlyphAtIndex:` (which return an NSPoint).